# How to see top 200 users for "popular question" badges on stack overflow

Tags: discussion

Is there an easy way to see the top 200 users for the "Popular Question" badge?  (Where the top person would have the most "Popular Question" badges.)

Comment: SEND SQL TO [DATAEXCHANGE](http://data.stackexchange.com/).  DATAEXCHANGES LOVE SQL.

Comment: Start with http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/965/users-with-most-nice-good-great-answers perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the tip Adam.

I was able to take the query and write this one:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1742/top-200-questioners

(Plus I learned how to create my own queries for future needs.)